# Is exp(-infinity) guaranteed to be zero in GLSL?

Tags: glsl

Is `exp(x)` where `x` is negative infinity guaranteed to evaluate to zero in GLSL?

Answer (score 1):

If you obtain negative infinity through that `-1/0.f`, you can try in your fragment shader to set your output color to `vec4(exp(-1/0.f),exp(-1/0.f),exp(-1/0.f), 1.f)` and see the color.
 I've just tried and the output is black(so equal to 0) in OGL 4.5. And by the limit of the exponential function, lim(-inf) = 0, so it must be a zero garanteed.
Hope this helped ^^.